# Azure Logic App HTTP Action step - dynamically get dates to use in querystring

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm creating an [Azure Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview). I've created a 'Recurrence' that will call a custom API endpoint every 12 hours. I want to pass dynamically calculated datetimes as querystring parameters when the API is called. Is this possible? I just need to get the current time, and a time 12 hours in the future. I discovered this guide to [date and time functions in expressions for Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#date-and-time-functions), but I'm not sure how to use these within my workflow:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Date and time functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#date-and-time-functions) as follows:

[image]

When you run it, the result will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @10p for the answer. Here's another screenshot that may help make it clearer how to add the function to get the value for the querystring

[image]